# Error on using GitBash when trying to start my first rails app

Tags: ruby, git-bash

> Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL
>   certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
>   There is a chance you are
>   experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system
>   doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
>   information about OpenSSL certificates, see
>   http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To
>   connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change
>   'https' to 'http'.

I am using windows.

Comment: So did you visit the site the error message recommended?  Did you follow the site's Windows advice?  https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Comment: it's telling you to change `https` to `http` in the Gemfile.